# What mean $X_n(\mathbb P)$ for $X_n$ r.v. and $\mu$ a measure on $\mathbb R$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

In the book "continuous martingales and brownian motion" of Yor-Revuz, page 16 theorem 1.2 says :

> Given a probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R$, there exist a probability space $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ and a sequence of independent r.v. $X_n$ defined on $\Omega $ s.t. $X_n(\mathbb P)=\mu$.

1) Could someone explain me what $X_n(\mathbb P)$ mean ?

2) Could someone explain me what this result/theorem mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution of $X_n$ under $\mathbb P$.  Remember $X_n$ will be a function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R$, so  it ``pushes'' the measure $\mathbb P$ forward to the measure $\nu = X_n(\mathbb P)$ defined by $\nu(A) = \mathbb P( \{\omega\in\Omega: X_n(\omega)\in A\})$; what the book claims is that $X_n$ can  be picked so this image measure $\nu$ is equal to the specified $\mu$, for all $n$. This is described in the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) with a slightly different notation with subscripted stars, as if Y&R had written ${(X_n)}_*(\mathbb P)$ or something.